# Status Bar disappearing When Searching

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, statusbar

I have a problem with my status bar .

it disappears as soon as i press on my search bar,Look at the examples :

Status bar shows normally before search bar pressed:
[image: Status bar shows normally before search bar pressed.]

Status bar does not show and just disappears out of view:
[image: Status bar does not show and just disappears out of view]

Thanks ahead ! :)

here is my searchController setup :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

definesPresentationContext = true
self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "חפש ברים"

}
```

Comment: it crashes my app again LOL XD here we go again @alexburtnik

Comment: Wait, what is crashing?

Comment: my app . and the debugger writes : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value and breakpoint shows error on the line : `self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`

Comment: You should not use forced unwrapped variables (! after type) before you initialize them. Move `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false` below next line

Comment: `override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
    }` i used this code to help me fix the problem but it only works for devices with iOS 10 and devices with iOS 9 still get the problem....

Comment: Have you tried setting Status Bar Style to `Light` in target settings -> General?

Comment: Ah it works for iOS 9 too now :) thanks ! can you write it as an answer so i can make it as the correct answer for you :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this setting:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

And override this function (Swift 2):

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle { 
    return .LightContent 
}
```